# HTML Form that creates a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is kind of an odd one. Long story short, I'm trying to add strings together using dropdown lists but I'm not quite sure how to go about it and searching for answers has borne no fruit.

I've tried any number of combinations of jquery, java, and HTML but nothing works *yet*

Example:

Selection 1: first-string
Selection 2: second-string
Selection 3: third string

I also need it to display the result of this on screen somewhere (I was trying to run a function via a button that would add the strings together and display them in a text box but it would only add numbers, not strings)

EDIT: I felt i'd fundementaly misunderstood...well just about everything I tried which is why I didn't share the code. But here we go:
                
                It is suggested you install a color picker to pair with this software
                
                
                    base = "000000";
                    eye = "FFFFFF";
                    nose = "000000";
                    m1c = "FFF000";
                    m2c = "00FFFF";
                    species = 1
                    m1 = 0
                    m2 = 0

```
                function feli() {
                    var m1 = document.getElementById("textbox1").value;
                    var answer = "http://www.felisfire.com/demo.php?s="+species+"&b"="+"base"+"&e="+"eye"+"&n="+"nose"+"&m1="+"m1"+"&m1c="+"m1c"+"&m2="+"m2"+"&m2c="+"m2c";
                    var textbox3 = document.getElementById('textbox3');
                        textbox3.value=answer;
                } 
            </script>
            Species
                <select name=species id=species>
                    <option value="1">Felidae</option>
                    <option value="3">Aquus</option>
                    <option value="8">Scalae</option>
                    <option value="5">Zerda</option>
                    <option value="6">Chetae</option>
                    <option value="10">Aurae</option>
                    <option value="7">Igneo</option>
                    <option value="9">Lycreon</option>
                    <option value="4">Iuridon</option>
                    <option value="2">Xano</option>
                </select>

            Marking 1
                <select name=m1 onChange = "m1 = this.value">
                    <option value="1">None</option>
                    <option value="12">Accents</option>
                    <option value="41">Anubis (p)</option>
                    <option value="13">Appaloosa</option>
                    <option value="15">Back Spots</option>
                    <option value="124">Badger</option>
                    <option value="44">Ball Python</option>
                </select>

            Marking 2
                <select name=m1 onChange = "m2 = this.value">
                    <option value="1">None</option>
                    <option value="12">Accents</option>
                    <option value="41">Anubis (p)</option>
                    <option value="13">Appaloosa</option>
                    <option value="15">Back Spots</option>
                    <option value="124">Badger</option>
                    <option value="44">Ball Python</option>
                </select>

            <input type="submit" name="button" id="button1" onclick="feli" value="Design!" />
            <input type="text" name="textbox3" id="textbox3" readonly="true"/>
            </div>
```

Comment: What you have tried till now? Please share your code.

Comment: Let we  dove in the deep end and started drowning in your code , kindly give us your half working/non working code

Comment: `$("#selection1").val() + $("#selection2").val() + $("#selection3").val()`

Comment: Before you can concatenate the strings together (which is the easy part) you need to be able to retrieve the value from each individual drop down (which is also pretty easy to do, with or without jQuery). Have you made any progress there at all? Please at least show the relevant html. Also, Java != Javascript.

Comment: We're not going to write it for you. Please show your attempt, and we'll help you understand where you went wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: Apologies, I figured my code was...well hacked apart and stitched back together, more a wish than a functional thing.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple to combine the string using JQuery.

```js
$("input").on("change", function () {
    $('#combine').val(($('#str1').val() +" "+ $('#str2').val()));   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="str1" />
<input type="text" id="str2" />
<input type="text" id="combine" />
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This code works.

If your HTML looks like this.

```
<select name="">
    <option value="">thisis 1</option>
    <option value="">thisis 2</option>
    <option value="">tisis 3</option>
    <option value="">thisis 4</option>
    <option value="">thisis 5</option>
</select>
<select name="">
    <option value="">thisis 1</option>
    <option value="">thisis 2</option>
    <option value="">thisis 3</option>
    <option value="">thisis 4</option>
    <option value="">thisis 5</option>
</select>
<select name="">
    <option value="">thisis 1</option>
    <option value="">thisis 2</option>
    <option value="">thisis 3</option>
    <option value="">thisis 4</option>
    <option value="">thisis 5</option>
</select>
<textarea name="" id="resulter" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

and you jQuery would look like this.

```
<script>

    $(function(){
        $('select').change(function(){
            // Get the selected option text
            var getText = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
            // Get the current textarea text
            var areaText = $('#resulter').text();
            // Concatenate the selected and area text together
            $('#resulter').text(areaText + getText);
        });

    });
</script>
```